# when jquery comes from CDN, are ajax calls cross-origin?

Tags: jquery, ajax, cors

I've recently started delegating to a CDN-hosted jquery, forgetting about my ajax calls being impacted by CORS -- oops. Surprisingly, we haven't seen browsers making much fuss about it! Specifically, as far as we can tell only one particular browser does a preflight OPTIONS (the agent is "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0"). Vast majority of browsers out there, including Chrome, FF or Safari are perfectly happy without the preflight -- one of the reasons why we didn't catch the problem in development/testing, that our OPTIONS request handling was lacking.

Please confirm if this scenario does in fact constitute CORS:

- file: app.js from Host-A
- file: jquery.js from CDN

app.js makes ajax-calls to its place of origin (Host-A) using jquery from CDN. Is IE11 the only one doing it right by issuing the preflight?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All ajax-calls have the origin Host-A. They have the origin of the domain of the original html document.

Comment: Thank you. Why in hell then we see sporadic OPTIONS requests sent by a small number of IE11 visitors (not all IE11 are affected) as of today... Has there been an update that introduced a bug recently? Specifically, today as of 13:50 UTC a handful of IE11 started requesting OPTIONS.

Comment: It may be the domain of the script matters for web workers or something.

Comment: @Debriter I don't think it's possible for us to say without a dump of the request and response headers (and possibly the relevant Ajax code). (And I think that's excellent ground for a new question.)